# Finding Known State Changes in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using SQL to detect a known state change in a table. Please see the columns below where the state moves from GOOD, BAD and UNDEFINED.

| date | row | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/08/2022 | Z | UNDEFINED |
| 19/08/2022 | Z | UNDEFINED |
| 18/08/2022 | Z | BAD |
| 17/08/2022 | Z | GOOD |
| 16/08/2022 | Z | GOOD |

Now see the column below where the state skips the BAD state and goes directly to UNDEFINED.

| date | row | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/08/2022 | Z | UNDEFINED |
| 19/08/2022 | Z | UNDEFINED |
| 18/08/2022 | Z | GOOD |
| 17/08/2022 | Z | GOOD |
| 16/08/2022 | Z | GOOD |

How can i detect the date on which the state entered UNDEFINED from GOOD. i.e my result should give me the two rows with date 19/08/2022 and 18/08/2022 capturing the change.

Comment: Do you only capture 1 status per day as your samples imply?

Comment: More detail needed, like would you definitely expect a record each day? But start with joining the table to itself using the row a < on the date. Then max the date for the less than side of the comparison and match batch to the status

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` to peek at the previous or next values. The, finding the rows is trivial.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    lag(status) over (order by date) as prev_status,
    lead(status) over (order by date) as next_status
  from t
) x
where status = 'UNDEFINED' and prev_status = 'GOOD'
   or status = 'GOOD' and next_status = 'UNDEFINED'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your MySql version doesn't support window functions and provided you don't have gaps, you can try the following with correlated *exists* criteria:

```
select * 
from t
where exists (
  select * from  t t2
  where t2.row = t.row 
    and (t.status='GOOD' and t2.status = 'UNDEFINED' and DateDiff(t2.date, t.date ) = 1)
    or (t.status='UNDEFINED' and t2.status = 'GOOD' and DateDiff(t.date, t2.date ) = 1)
);
```